# How can I access name of enum in typescript

Tags: typescript, enums

I am using a library that has an emum that looks like this:

```
/** Defines values that represent the status of a request to purchase an app or add-on. */
enum StorePurchaseStatus {
    /** The current user has already purchased the specified app or add-on. */
    alreadyPurchased = 1,
    /** The purchase request did not succeed because of a network connectivity error. */
    networkError = 3,
    /** The purchase request did not succeed. */
    notPurchased = 2,
    /** The purchase request did not succeed because of a server error returned by the Windows Store. */
    serverError = 4,
    /** The purchase request succeeded. */
    succeeded = 0,
}
```

I have the number value and I want to print the name (ex. I have a status of 1 and want to print 'alreadyPurchased').

However, when I do something like this:

```
StorePurchaseStatus[1]
```

I end up getting `undefined`. How can I access the string name if I only have the value?

Comment: What version of Typescript are you using? This works as expected for me in Typescript 2.7 (via the Typescript playground).

Comment: I'm using 2.3.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you wrote in the original post is good. You can check this [Playground example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=enum%20StorePurchaseStatus%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20current%20user%20has%20already%20purchased%20the%20specified%20app%20or%20add-on.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20alreadyPurchased%20%3D%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20purchase%20request%20did%20not%20succeed%20because%20of%20a%20network%20connectivity%20error.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20networkError%20%3D%203%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20purchase%20request%20did%20not%20succeed.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20notPurchased%20%3D%202%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20purchase%20request%20did%20not%20succeed%20because%20of%20a%20server%20error%20returned%20by%20the%20Windows%20Store.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20serverError%20%3D%204%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%2F**%20The%20purchase%20request%20succeeded.%20*%2F%0A%20%20%20%20succeeded%20%3D%200%2C%0A%7D%0A%0Aalert(StorePurchaseStatus%5B1%5D)%3B%20%2F%2F%20alreadyPurchased%0A%0Aalert(StorePurchaseStatus%5BStorePurchaseStatus%5B1%5D%5D)%3B%2F%2F%201).

Here is how to access the name and the value:

```
alert(StorePurchaseStatus[1]); // alreadyPurchased
alert(StorePurchaseStatus[StorePurchaseStatus[1]]);// 1
```